# delay between key input(ctrl+alt+t) and starting terminal window

Tags: command-line, 16.04, performance

I have a problem with starting terminal. The problem occurs when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> there is a delay of about 30 sec when terminal shows up.

What could cause this? 
My PC configuration is here:
[image: PC configuration]

At the moment my PC consumes:
[image: PC consumes at the moment]

Currently I am running InteliJ server application, Android studio - debugging android app, along with 33 opened tabs in Chrome, android emulator for android application.
I know that this is bunch of applications up and running, but this started to occur a few days ago.
Can you help me to solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: perhaps you are reaching the maximum number of processes per user?
Right before you issue CTRL-ALT T, check ulimit -a. Then ps -ef | grep 'your user' | wc -l

Comment: ulimit - a: 
[link](http://tinypic.com/r/a5kyeh/9)
ps -ef | grep 'your user' | wc -l: 1

Comment: Well, that does not seem to be the cause then. Maybe find a relation to the many tabs in Chrome and memory consumption would be my next thought.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time and effort, I really appreciate that